# Automatic create function block diagram from ansi c code

Tags: c, diagram

Does anyone know a tool that is able to create "function diagrams" from ansi c code?

By "function diagram" I mean a chart that represents an overview of files, functions and their relations. I imagine it to be something like a circut diagram.

Eg. if have the following code:

```
//MyProgram.c
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo();
    Bar();
    return 0;
}

//Slave.h
void Foo();
void Bar();
```

The chart would be something like the following picture:

[image: Function relation diagram]

Does it have an official name? Dependency diagram, perhaps?

I've looked at bit on Doxygen. But that one clearly states that:
*Doxygen has built-in support to generate inheritance diagrams for C++ classes.*
Same thing with many UML tools. I don't have any classes. Although my c files may come close.

Comment: Perhaps I should add that my purpose with the diagram, is to present an overview of a given code project. A helpful hand in "finding the right place to look, in the code". Grouping of files and libs are therefor important. And the function relations will give the actual content. Perhaps you know a better diagram? Something file/lib based?

Comment: The "Dependency graph" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657798.aspx, actually looks fairly good. It just lacks the function relations.

Comment: doxygen is capable to extract all kinds of graphs, not only inheritence diagrams.

Answer (score 5):

What you refers is called [Call Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph).

There's a list of tools to generate them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph#Software

Comment: Most call graphs that I've seen, put all functions into one big bucket and then generates a tree (if lucky). They're very nice when doing profiling. In this case, I'm more interested in the relationship between files, than the sequence of the call graph. UML would be a better hit I think. But perhaps you have a specific program in mind?

Comment: Most of the IDE's already support call graphs these days.

Comment: I've looked through the list and I cannot find any that're able to create a "file ordered call graphs". They're just trees with the main-call function as top node. (And I'm not really looking for trees at all.)

Answer (score 3):

There couple of software which are not free anymore e.g [www.scitools.com](http://www.scitools.com) which has a tool called `Understand C`. This I'm sure will do what you are looking for, there are other tools like BOUML ( this is free tool). Other than this the list provided by `qiao` is good reference.

Comment: scitool has some interesting graphs. Their dependency graph is close: http://www.scitools.com/images/features/dependenciesGraph.png. Still it doesn't show function relations and it certainly doesn't gives an overview. Anyone looking at these will run away screeming. (A matter of taste and complexity perhaps.)

Comment: true, but it still does what you need. I assume you don't want to generate or regenerate code.

Comment: If I understood your requirements correctly , scitools definitely does what you need. Please explore the tool and you'll get to know. I'm sure they still have trail version.

Comment: The Hierachy graph is better: http://www.scitools.com/images/features/graph_views_c_calls.png. It's lacking all file relations though and it's biased towards the calling function.

Comment: No, I don't want to generate code etc. It's for documentation.

Comment: scitools also got a tool to publish document from the code comments, but I think the tool is different.

Comment: scitools might have a useful diagram (although it doesn't seem to have what I'm looking for). But it's also a program that costs 5k-10k$. (My personal guess.) And I have no use for 99% of the program. It might be cheaper to hire someone to create a few diagrams by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the origin of my idea. Displaying code as "components with connected input/output" is a LabVIEW concept. (I'm not a complete nutter for seeking out this kind diagram then ;)

However as far as I know, LabVIEW doesn't do what I want it to. LabVIEW is for building and connecting functionality. Widely used by hw/fw people. (Which are also my target audience.) It will not reverse engineer code into diagrams.

Strange that these diagrams doesn't really exists. It seems to me that people such as embedded programmers, ansi c, low level, hw etc. would love them.